# How can a Lilliputian civilisation parasitise a human body?

Tags: humans

This Lilliputian civilisation is a technological civilisation and a typical Lilliputian is about 0.08 mm tall. Apart of the size constrain, they can have any shape or biology adapted to this scale. Two hundred of them are currently travelling in a tiny amphibian spaceship and they are looking for a human body to set up a settlement.

What is the best place to land and settle?

They need food, oxygen and a power supply and they will enjoy better the place if it is safe, light and not too hot or too humid.

They have advanced technological knowledge so they can defend themselves against other parasites like lice or the host's immune system.

Comment: I think you might need to elaborate on your tiny humans a little bit and how you envision them settling. Not only is a human body that size not scientifically feasible to my knowledge, but you also have to take into account there is a immune system that fights off foreign objects. What exactly do you mean by food? They obviously don't eat what humans eat as all that is unsuitable for an organism that size. They could eat the human from the inside. After all it is organic matter. You need to be a lot more specific with this question or it is likely to be closed.

Comment: You need to specify what you are willing to handwave and what is supposed to be scientifically reasonable. If you don't this question is just pure opinion and thus can't be answered properly.

Comment: For context: At the scale of an ant, water has very different properties from what we're used to. You are positing one to two orders of magnitude smaller still. Lots of things that we take for granted are different at those scales.

Comment: you cannot go inside of the human because your lilliputs could not breathe, and of course the immune system would kill them. But maybe they could settle between the human's hair?

Comment: @ArtificialSoul You're right I edited my question

Comment: What is the difference between food and fuel?  Carbohydrates are fuel for our bodies.  The need for light might be an issue.  The leaves the eyes or on the skin.  They could be just under the first layer of skin if they don't land on someone from Africa.  They could go deeper if they found a Scandinavian (and freckles would provide great shade).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your "Lilliputians" are the size of dust [mites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mite). They will be barely visible on a human being. This answer will assume they are sapient and have technological civilization. Their amphibian spaceship is evidence of these facts. It will not assume they are humanoid or anything close to humanoid. They are alien creatures the size of [dust mites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_dust_mite).

The fact they are seeking a human body to colonize is an indicator that on their home planet there are large animals that act as hosts to their parasitic civilization.

The most likely site for their colonization and settlement will be on the skin of their human host. Areas of the human anatomy covered by hair will be the most probable sites. The top of the head and the pubis. This is airy, this means oxygen will eb accessible and available, not too humid or too hot, and an excellent location for solar power collectors. Any solar energy technology will be far advanced beyond what we have currently developed. If they have space travel, their solar energy technology will be comparably more advanced.

Food. That be will be gathered from oils, skin fragments and the bacteria that colonize the human epidermis. If necessary they could drill into the skin and extract nutrients from the interior of the human host.

> Many mites are parasitic on plants and animals. One family of mites, Pyroglyphidae, or nest mites, live primarily in the nests of birds and animals. These mites are largely parasitic and consume blood, skin and keratin. Dust mites, which feed mostly on dead skin and hair shed from humans instead of consuming them from the organism directly, evolved from these parasitic ancestors.

Source: [Parasitism in mites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mite)

This generally assumes the "Lilliputians" are functionally mites as we know them on planet Earth. Whatever structures they set up on their host will depend on a more detailed knowledge of their biology, anatomy, reproduction, and ecology. To say nothing of their culture and social organization.

Also, we will need to be careful about how they use their advanced technology. Having amphibian spaceships blasting off and landing on the head of their human hosts might bring unwanted attention to their presence. Humans have developed a considerable measures for removing ectoparasites like lice from their bodies. The "Lilliputians" may need to be discreet with their technology.

In conclusion, the head and pubis seem to be the most probable sites for "Lilliputian" settlement on a human host. With the head offering the most benefits.

Comment: Space-faring pubic lice that drill into your unsuspecting mons and sap your blood. +1 for making OPs world a bit more horrible.

Comment: @Inoutguttiwutts You're welcome. Making worlds more horrible is a free service. Should you need a world made more horrible, please call. We always value new customers.